# ASP.NET MVC Fill a label at the click of a button

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I'm working on an email sending application. I have created a method to receive all emails. My goal now is to create a button of the genre (Select all) and the label for the recipient appear there all the emails contained in the database when I click on the button. My problem is that I do not know where to start nor do I have any examples

**Method**

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult GetEmails ()
{
   ProjectEntities entities = new ProjectEntities ();
   var emails =  from User in entities.Use
                 select User.Email;

   return Json(emails);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hi Dário, welcome to stack.**

From your question i assume you are working on a Asp.net mvc application where you want to show a button in your view page(Html page) and when this button will be clicked then you will retrieve some data from database(as you already wrote a method for that).
To achieve that first you have to create a button in view. you can write some html code like below

```
 <div id="label_id"> 
   //comment: In this div email address will be shown after getting it from 
  //server.
 </div>
 <input type="button" id="btn_submit" value="submit"/>
```

Now you have to write a click event which will fire when someone click the submit button. It will send a post request using Ajax to server and get back your email address. please check jquery code, do not forget to add jquery link to your view file.

```
$(document).on('click','#btn_submit', function(){

$.ajax({ 
 type: 'POST', 
 url: 'Controller/GetEmails',  
 dataType: 'json',
 success: function (data) {
  //comment you will find email address from this data object.
  //bind data to view.
  $('#label_id').html(data);
 }
});
});
```

you can check [this](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/ASPNet-MVC-jQuery-AJAX-and-JSON-Example.aspx)
 article for better understanding of Asp.net mvc and Ajax

Comment: Thank you very much for the help and I think I am almost getting the desired one. The only thing left to be excellent is that by clicking on the button, the label is not yet filled, I think this is from javacript. Can you give me some final help?

Comment: Glad it helps, as you receive some json data from server response so use json parser to parse then write it to console to see what you recieve.

    var json_data= json.parse(data);
    console.log(json_data);

Comment: User messages, no browser, I get all the emails that the method returns. The only problem is that they do not appear on the label as desired.

Comment: I solved the problem with this $('#email').val(data);